# How to hide admin login section to regular users

Tags: php, laravel, user-experience

I'm creating my first website from scratch with laravel for someone I know, and it will be kind of a landing page for his business, but he wants an admin section for managing some stuff.

My question is how, in the real world, we integrate a login section so only administrators can access it ? I mean I think there's a way so regular users can not see it.

**There won't be any registration for users**. The administrator will already be registered in the database.

Thanks

Comment: I see on stackoverflow there are some people who just look at the posts so they can thumb it down, without even answering it, very smart guys !

Comment: this topic is broad .

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, many solutions can be found, some easy, and some more complex.

In 99% cases, everyone can access the login page. The aim of login is to prevent unauthorized users to access  your private website section. So if users can't login, you simply can't access and your own to the backoffice. So the easiest solution is : juste dont put any link in your all users access pages redirecting to your login form.

You could try something as blockig all IP address axcept your friend's one and other stuffs with MAC addresses, but the problems will become harder if you've set it to MAC address and your computer die, same for IP address if you don't have one etc...

But really keep in mind that logins are usually (in the real world) accessible from everyone... Dont try to add other weird stuffs to secure it more. Furthermore the laravel Authentication is really good and you don't need at all to change or boost it...

Comment: You made me think of something, I will make a route for /admin only accessible by typing in the url. Thanks

Comment: @naspy971 Even better idea is not to name the url `/admin` but say `/backoffice` or something like that